# how to increase the screen recording time in a custom rom?

Tags: android, rom, rpscreenrecorder

is there a way to increase the recording time and the GB limit by modifying some of the systemui an aosp rom (arrow 11) since after 9:38 min with a weight of 4.5 GB the screen is finished recording

i tried to modify the systemui but no result.